# How can I write a conditional statement for not repeating certain values in React/Redux calculator?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, calculator

This is for the *freecodecamp.org* **React/Redux** projects.

---

I'm coding a calculator and I'm passing every test except for #11 and #13.

Here's a link to the tests I need to pass for this project: https://learn.freecodecamp.org/front-end-libraries/front-end-libraries-projects/build-a-javascript-calculator

Here's the part of my code I can't get right:

```
const calcReducer = (state = calcState, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'ADD':
      return{
        ...state,
        value: state.value == 0 ? action.text : state.value + action.text
        }
    case 'OPERATOR': ***//this part is what I think is wrong. Everything else functions how it should***
      return{
        ...state,
        value: action.text == regex + regex ? action.text - regex : state.value = action.text
        }
```

And before anyone asks, my regex is setup and logging correctly through the console.

I appreciate any help I can get on this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are mutating the redux state in that ternary operator:

`value: action.text == regex + regex ? action.text - regex : state.value = action.text`

The last part here: `state.value = action.text` is mutating state.

Try changing it to:

`value: action.text == regex + regex ? action.text - regex : action.text`

Also the `'ADD'` ternary here:

`value: state.value == 0 ? action.text : state.value + action.text`

is not needed.  You can shorten it to this:

`value: state.value + action.text`

Comment: I tried out your suggestion and it still doesn't seem to be working. Could it be because of the 'ADD' case also mutating the state?

Comment: No your 'ADD' case isn't mutating the state but the ternary there is unnecessary.  I edited my answer to reflect that.  Try logging your redux state and check what is happening with each action to see why it isn't working.  It could be your regex

Comment: I wrote the regex to match only the symbols and it does. There aren't any errors in my console. My debugging skills are a little rusty, but I couldn't see anything wrong with my cases either. And the 'ADD' case has to be done the way I had it or it'll prepend a zero to everything as opposed to displaying the zero and having it disappear as soon as someone clicks a different button. It's part of the tests I have to passed.

Comment: Here's a link to the whole thing: [link](https://codepen.io/DreamSpinner22/pen/QWLPYVL)

Comment: if it is prepending a 0 that means `action.text` is a string not a number.  I would try adding `Number(action.text)` to make sure you are only adding numbers and it's not trying to concat

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using a combination of conditional statements and ternary expressions. I wrote a function called handleOperator and passed 'action.text' in as an argument in my switch case 'OPERATOR' using a ternary expression which disallows other operators to be appended to 'state.value', excluding the negative sign.

Here's my code for the function and the switch case:

````
  var input = document.getElementById('display').value;
  var inpArr = [];
  if (endsWithNegativeSign.test(input) == true && isOperator.test(value)) {
    input = input.replace(isOperator, value);
    return input.replace(value, '');
  }
  return false;
}
const handleOperator = (value) => {
  var input = document.getElementById('display').value;
  if (endsWithOperator.test(input) == true) {
    return input.replace(lastChar, value);
  }
  return false;
}


//Setup Reducer
const calcReducer = (state = calcState, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'ADD':
      return{
        ...state,
        value: (state.value == 0) ? action.text : state.value + action.text
      }
    case 'OPERATOR':
      return{
        ...state,
        value: endsWithOperator.test(state.value) == true && action.text != '-' ? handleOperator(action.text) : endsWithNegativeSign.test(state.value) == true ? handleNegative(action.text) : containsDecimal.test(state.value) == true ? handleDecimal(action.text) : state.value + action.text```
````